# ElasticSearch and SpringData: FindAll and OrderBy

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to get all documents, ordered by a certain fied (`parent` in my case).

In my `ItemRepository` I added following signature:

```
public List<Item> findAllOrderByParent();
```

But by invoking it, I get a

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed;
nested exception is
  org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: 
    Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!
```

The same postponing `Asc` or `Desc` to the method name.

Somewhere I read the correct syntax should be the following (note the extra `By` just after `findAll`):

```
public List<Item> findAllByOrderByParent();
```

Here I get a

```
NullPointerException
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.count(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:54)
...
```

I'm excluding other issues because declaring a method like public `List<Item> findByNameOrderByParent();` everithing works fine.

Do you have an idea to proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit late but since the problem is still there, to get around it I just used the findAll method using a Sort object as param:

```
List<Item> findAll(Sort sort);
```

and you call it:

```
List<Item> items = this.itemRepository.findAll(new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name")));
```

**The "name" property you can extract it in a constant or make your service's listItems method to support dynamic sort and send the sort field as a parameter.**

You can also have a look at this article: http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/05/09/sorting-spring-data-mongodb-collections-using-orderby/

Comment: Yes, it's a bit late :) and I solved by directly using elasticsearch API... Until last summer (I don't know new evolutions) Spring-data-EsalsticSearch was a very young project, working fine only for a certain set of basic operations... By the way thanks for sharing (I think someone else will arrive here in future)