# Date Conversion Exception in Spring Boot and ElasticSearch Document

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-repositories

While i running my Spring Boot code (with have ElasticSearch), i give an error.

i want to list get that all exist element in my elasticsearch vehicle document

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: Unable to convert value '2022-01-01' to java.util.Date for property 'created'
```

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821617/elasticsearch-and-springdata-findall-and-orderby) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251141/springboot-elasticsearch-date-convert-conversionexception) links.

But didnt work.

How can i fix this problem.?

Following code its my Vehicle class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = Indicies.VEHICLE_INDEX)
public class Vehicle {

@Id
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String number;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String name;

@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
private Date created;

}
```

Following interface its my VehicleRepository Interface

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Vehicle, String> {

    Page<Vehicle> findAll();

}
```

Following code its my Service Method for getList

```
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicleList() {
        return vehicleRepository.findAll().getContent();
    }
```

Following code its my Vehicle Controller Endpoint

```
    private final VehicleService vehicleService;

    @GetMapping("/vehicle-list")
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicleList() {
        return vehicleService.getVehicleList();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The date that is store in your index seems to be a local date ("2022-01-01", no time zone, no timestamp). `java.util.Date` is an instant in time in the UTC timezone. You cannot convert a date-only string into a Date. Your pattern String that contains a time that does not match the string either.

And don't use the ancient `java.util.Date` class, use the classes from the `java.time` package which are available since Java 8.

You should use

```java
@Field(type = Date, format = DateFormat.date)
LocalDate created;
```

and have the index recreated to adjust the mapping.

Comment: Thank you very match. This is worked. (((:

Comment: then yu should accept the answer ;-)